# Get the latest record with limit in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

**My model**

```
public function getLogs()
{
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $query = $this->db->get('tbllogs');

    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? What is the question?

Comment: Zayn Ali already answered it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
$this->db->limit(5);
$query = $this->db->get('tbllogs');

return $query->result();
```

Or for `old` and `latest` logic make two links in your view with `orderBy` query parameter in it.

```
<a href="/controller/method?orderBy='old'">Old</a>
<a href="/controller/method?orderBy='latest'">Latest</a>
```

In your controller method

```
if ($this->input->get('orderBy') == 'old') {
    $this->db->order_by("id", "asc");
} else {
    $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
}

$this->db->limit(5);
$query = $this->db->get('tbllogs');

return $query->result();
```

Comment: Any suggestion? What if i'll put some button to my view and when it clicked the oldest logs will be shown?

Comment: Thank you, it helped me alot!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

With where condition

```
$result = $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC')->limit(5)->get_where($tablename,$where);
```